# Monitoring firebase storage uploads

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a flutter app that takes a picture every 5 seconds and stores it under a custom folder inside the bucket. There are 5 instances of this app running in different places, each one uploading the picture every 5 seconds to its proper folder. However, sometimes the app crashes, and if I forget to check the folders, it may be idle for days before I notice. Today this is about to scale up to 300 devices, so my goal is to monitor this behaviour and get notified by email or sms whenever this happens.

The condition would be if a certain folder doesn't receive new data for, let say 5 mins, it should trigger the alert. Is there a way to achieve this using the features that firebase provides, or should I develop this custom functionality?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing can't be automated completely. You're going to have to build a custom solution using the products provided by Google that are accessible to Firebase and Google Cloud projects.  You have some options:

- Use a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd) to periodically check some piece of data (probably in a database somewhere that you choose) to see if it hasn't changed in some amount of time.  It will be the responsibility of your app to update that data with a timestamp so that the function can check to see the last time it ran.
- Use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to schedule some code to run after some amount of time from the last event.  If the event is a Storage upload, you can write a storage trigger to kick off that task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check it more in depth